# Best way to assign the same function to buttons in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, button

I wanted to know how I can optimize my current code.
I use buttons which are generated when an item is created it increases/decreases its value in a table. The button is pushed into an array this array iterates through all buttons in this array and give them a function based on their id.

```
var increaseButtonArray = [];
var increaseButton = 'increaseButton' + obj.id;
$('#d' + i + 'Content').append('<tr>' + 
'<td><button type="button" id="' + increaseButton + '">...
increaseButtonArray.push(increaseButton);
```

Because I use 4 button for each element I can't just give the button the id of the element I instead make "the name of the button" + the id of the element.

```
function increaseButtonFunction() {
        $.each(increaseButtonArray, function (index, obj) {
            $("#" + obj).click(function btnClick() {
                var x = obj.substring(14, 17);
                $.each(list.List, function (k, v) {
                    $.each(v, function (index, obj2) {
                        if (obj2.id == x) {
                            obj2.value = obj2.value+ 1;
                        }
                    });
                });
                drawRow();
            });
        })
    }
```

To find the button I use substring(I know that is bad practice) but my code currently works and the application only uses <40 elements.

What is a cleaner solution for this?

**UPDATE**
Working Snippet

https://jsfiddle.net/9vh2ebqk/

Comment: Sounds like https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for that kind of questions specifically, stackoverflow is (rather) about code that **doesn't** work. Interesting question, anyway.

Comment: I agree that codereview is a better place to ask, but just some heads up: you probably want a templating engine. Maybe have a look at mustache

Answer (score 0):

I had make a more flexible version of inc and dec button.

```
`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pm01z4of/
`

Don't understand what should exactly happen with set and delete but anyway I hope it helps you.